# AutoMapper and different objects

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have list of objects like the following:

```
A: IBaseType
{
   string X
   DateTime Y
   int Z
}
```

and I want to get after mapping three different objects that are produced based on their properties.

For instance:

```
Mapper.Map<IList<A>, IList<IBaseType>>(list);
```

and in output collection get different objects

```
X: IBaseType
{
  string X;
}

Y: IBaseType
{
   DateTime Y
}
```

and so on.

Or in something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemModel>().FromMap(d=>d.Conditions, opt=>(there some like to IValueResovler );
```

Comment: I don't think AutoMapper supports that (assuming that is your question).

Comment: @driis do you know how I could to do this?

Comment: You'd probably need to write the type-selecting code yourself. After determining the type you want an `A` instance mapped to, you can (probably) use AutoMapper to map the properties.

Comment: Ok, I see. Therefore there no way to incorporate this with AutoMapper? to use value resolver, formatter or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best way is to implement custom mapping functionality.

Something like this:

```
public IBaseType Map(A item)
{
     if ( /*your condition*/ )
          return new X(){ X = item.X}

     else if ( /*your condition*/ )
          return new Y(){ Y = item.X}
}
```

and use this method

```
List<IBaseType> result = new List<IBaseType>() ;
list.Foreach(x => result.Add(Map(x)));
```

Comment: I did this in that way. But, I try to solve this through AutoMapper.